# Refreshing Vm-Instance on Google Cloud

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

My Cpu Utilitzation went above 100% when i Installed a new theme and was trying to setup it's settings. But after that I can't reach ip address it says "" I wanted to suspend and resume the instance. Can anyone tell me if it will give any problems. How can I solve this issue.

> This site can’t be reached
> domain.com took too long to respond.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be two reasons for this behaviour-- It could be a problem with your instance or with the IP.

If you don't have your external IP address reserved, the IP will be released when you stop your   instance and when you start your instances again, GCP will provide a new External IP.

You can check what External IP you have on the [External IP addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses?_ga=2.238285376.1137955818.1597064302-638966553.1591892739), and try to access your WordPress site through this new IP.

To avoid this problem in the future you can promote your ephemeral external IP address, you can use this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) as reference or follow the next steps:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the **[External IP addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses?_ga=2.238285376.1137955818.1597064302-638966553.1591892739)** page.
2. In the **Type** column, change the address type to **Static** for the IP address you want to promote.
3. Provide a name for the new static IP address and click **Reserve**.

In this way, the next time you stop your instance you will keep your IP.

Please keep in mind that, if your IP address has changed, you need to update your DNS with the new IP.

Additionally, I suggest increasing your resources per your convenience to enhance your performance, because the behaviour you mentioned in your CPU usage is a good indicator that your existing machine type is not a good fit for your workloads you run on that instance.

Changing a machine type

1.- Go to the [VM Instances page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?_ga=2.127259917.1890227771.159585545).

2.- In the Name column, click on your instance.

3. From the instance details page, complete the following steps:

   a) Click the Stop button to stop the instance, if you have not stopped it yet.

   b) After the instance stops, click the Edit button at the top of the page.

   c) Under the Machine configuration section, select the machine type you want to use.

   d) Save your changes and start again your VM Instance.

I suggest to reserve the IP before any change in your instance.

On the other hand, I recommend you review the following guides on asking questions in order to provide a better context on what you're doing and what you want to achieve: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)